# How to pull in-sample fitted models towards out-of-sample optimum during training?

Tags: ratio, out-of-sample, differences, training-error

A common problem in prediction problems is getting a model fit on in-sample data to predict out-of-sample data with decent accuracy and precision. Assuming that we break a part of the in-sample data off and call it the validation set, are there any techniques in learning optimization/evaluation that take into account in-sample and out-of-sample performance *simultaneously* during the training step in the form of, say, a *ratio* of in-sample vs out-of-sample performance?

There is almost always a difference between the in-sample and out-of-sample performance. How can this difference be narrowed or squeezed during the actual training of the model? Simply minimizing an error objective function falls short of what I mean because that is always separated into minimizing training error and *then* minimizing test error. What I'm looking for is an immediate quantification of the *tension between* (pulling of) the in-sample vs out-of-sample performance, meaning the training and prediction happens concurrently, but is tuned at that very step based on the quantified in-sample/out-of-sample difference/tension measure or ratio.

Comment: The cross-validation will do though it is used for OOS performance evaluation usually.

Comment: not what i'm looking since cross-validation, at least ordinarily, seperates the in-sample and out-of-sample steps